# how does browser relate a cookie to the server it sends the cookie to?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

How does browser relate a cookie to the server it sends the cookie to?

And if cookies are disabled, what other way can be used to store session_cookies on the client browser?

Comment: PHP can be configured to pass the session id in the URL as a query string parameter, but that practice is discouraged as it can easily be used maliciously, plus all links have to be able to include the session id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does browser relate a cookie to the server it sends the cookie to?

They [normalise the domain name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.2), then [check which cookies match the domain](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3), then [check that the path in the cookie is the same as the start of the path for the request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.4).

> And if cookies are disabled, what other way can be used to store session_cookies on the client browser?

There isn't another way. If cookies are disabled, then cookies are disabled.

You can temporarily store data in other, non-cookie ways. A common approach used to be to store the data in the query string. This can cause security issues as it can leak through referers and people copy/pasting links.

In general, if you need to track a user, then explain why and ask them to enable cookies.